# Aditionnal price to product in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, shopping-cart, prestashop-1.6

I am selling drinks in bottles that have a deposit price. The customer has to pay that amount, but can get it back by bringing the bottles to a supermarket. I would like to show the product price without the deposit in the product pages, but when the user checks out his cart, this amount needs to be added to the cart for each item having a deposit. Here are some extra info:
Not all products have a deposit
The deposit price depends on the product

I managed to add a "deposit" field to the backoffice in the product page:

http://oi57.tinypic.com/6p9s80.jpg

But it seems that changing the whole workflow of the cart check out would be quite a pain. Is there any easy way to achieve this task?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easiest way to do what you want it is using "product attributes combinations" + little code changes, step by step:

1. create product attribute e.g. "deposit"
2. add value to it, any,e.g. "yes"
3. in product create combination with "deposit: yes", set price impact value as you need, e.g. "$10" and set it as default combination
4. to show on product page price without "deposit" change in `themes/themename/js/product.js` in `function updatePrice()` find lines

   `// Apply combination price impact
   // 0 by default, +x if price is inscreased, -x if price is decreased
   basePriceWithoutTax = basePriceWithoutTax + +combination.price;`

and wrap it into condition:

```
if( your_attribute_id != combination.attributes[0] ) {    
    basePriceWithoutTax = basePriceWithoutTax + +combination.price;
}
```

but in cart you will see full price.

UPD:

5. I see no good way to do it in template, without  core changes, so if you need it (solution also not ideal)
   file `controllers/front/CategoryController.php` ([use override](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Overriding+default+behaviors)) method `assignProductList()` change code block to next view:

   ```
   foreach ($this->cat_products as &$product) {
       if ($product['id_product_attribute'] && isset($product['product_attribute_minimal_quantity']))
           $product['minimal_quantity'] = $product['product_attribute_minimal_quantity'];
       $combination = new Combination($product['id_product_attribute']);
       $attributes = $combination->getAttributesName($this->context->language->id);
       foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
           if(your_attribute_id == $attribute['id_attribute'])
               $product['price_tax_exc'] -= $combination->price;
       }
   }
   ```

you will need to repeat it for all lists controllers that you use (and you can do not use foreach but access to array element by index like you already did), in any case solution very project specific, just quick fix, in common case be better use other ways.

Comment: HI, thanks for your answer! The idea is good, and I was going with the combination trick. The problem is that this only works on the product page but not on the product list page (and all other lists of products like featured, best sales, etc.). Any idea?

Comment: Also, I had to adapt your code to `if(combination.attributes[0] == 1) {
  basePriceWithoutTax = basePriceWithoutTax + +combination.price;
 }` because it's the id attribute that I have to compare, id_product_attribute is different for each product.

Comment: `combination.attributes[0] != 1`of course! (sorry for the spam, couldn't edit my comment anymore)

Comment: Thanks for your update and comment, i'll try that now. The only thing is, as i said, id_product_attribute varies with each product, even when using the same attribute. Since deposit has the attribute id 1 and will only have one value ('yes'), isn't it enough to only check the attribute id?

Comment: correct, you can use it (my inattention). I'll change my answer for all cases

Comment: But attribute id it does not appear in the $product properties in product-list.tpl... Do I have to overwrite Product.php ?

Comment: yes, there is only default product attribute id appear, now I think how to do it better, without many core changes, cause will needed override not only Category controller, but each that shows lists of products.